# SUDOKU solver in c++

Tags: c++, sudoku

I need help to make a Sudoku solver in C++.

Requirements of the program:

1. Input Sudoku:[Done]
2. Read Sudoku: [Done]
3. Validate function: (validates the Sudoku:) [Done]
4. Display function [done]
5. solve function [need help]

My plan:

- Make a function to validate the sudoku [done]
  and assign possibility of 1-9 for every blank colume. and perform a brute-force
  method to solve the puzzle. It will call the function validate each time
  while doing brute force. It consumes a lot of time and I understood that it is
  impossible.

I need a better algorithm for the `solve` function, please help me.

I have commented some of the code just to analyses the code: Apologize if that is the wrong way.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
/*  Program: To solve a SU-DO-KU: 
    Date:23-sep-2013 @ 5.30:
*/


#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int su_in[9][9]={
                 0,0,7   ,0,0,0    ,4,0,6,
                 8,0,0   ,4,0,0    ,1,7,0,
                 0,0,0   ,3,0,0    ,9,0,5,
                 
                 0,0,0   ,7,0,5    ,0,0,8,
                 0,0,0   ,0,0,0    ,0,0,0,
                 4,0,0   ,2,0,8    ,0,0,0,
                 
                 7,0,4   ,0,0,3    ,0,0,0,
                 0,5,2   ,0,0,1    ,0,0,9,
                 1,0,8   ,0,0,0    ,6,0,0   
                };
int su_out[9][9];/*={


                 5,3,7   ,9,1,2    ,4,8,6,
                 8,2,9   ,4,5,6    ,1,7,3,
                 6,4,1   ,3,8,7    ,9,2,5,
                 
                 9,1,3   ,7,4,5    ,2,6,8,
                 2,8,6   ,1,3,9    ,7,5,4,
                 4,7,5   ,2,6,8    ,3,9,1,
                 
                 7,6,4   ,8,9,3    ,5,1,2,
                 3,5,2   ,6,7,1    ,8,4,9,
                 1,9,8   ,5,2,4    ,6,3,7
                };*/
            
struct chance{
    
    int poss[9];
    
};              
                
int box_validate(int,int,int);
void read(int);
void display(int);
int validate(int);
int solve();

int main()
{   
    int i,j,row,get_res=2;
    
    enum {input=1,output};
    
    cout<<"enter the sudoku: use 0 if the colum is empty:\n";
    
//  for(i=0; i<9; i++){
//  read(i);
//  }
    
    cout<<"\n\t\tTHE ENTERED SU-DO-CU IS:\n\n";
    display(input);
    
    get_res=validate(input);
    
    if(get_res==0)
        cout<<"valid input!\n";
        else if(get_res==1)
           cout<<"invalid input!\n";

//  display(input);
    for(i=0; i<9; i++)
    for(j=0; j<9; j++)
    su_out[i][j]=su_in[i][j];
    
//  display(output);
    get_res=validate(output);
    
    if(get_res==0){
        cout<<"valid solution!\n"; display(output);}
    //  else if(get_res==1)
    //     cout<<"invalid sudoku!\n";
    
    if(solve()==0) display(output);
    else cout<<"not solved buddy!!\n";


}




void read(int row) // function to read the SU-DO-CU
{   
    unsigned num,i;
    cout<<"enter the row:'"<<row+1<<"'\n";
    
    for(i=0; i<9;   i++)
    {
    cin>>num;
    if(num<0||num>9)
    cout<<"error! invalid input: enter a number < or = 9 and > or = 0 \n";
    else
    su_in[row][i]=num;
    }
}


void display(int sudoku) // function to display the SU-DO-CU
{
    unsigned i,j;
    
        for(i=0;i<9; i++)
        {   
            if(i%3==0)
            cout<<"\t\t-------------------------\n";    
            
            cout<<"\t\t";
            for(j=0; j<9; j++)
                {   
                    if(j%3==0)
                    cout<<"| ";
            
            //      if(su[i][j]==0)
            //      cout<<"_ ";
            //      else    
                    if(sudoku==1)
                    cout<<su_in[i][j]<<" ";
                    
                    else if(sudoku==2)
                    cout<<su_out[i][j]<<" ";
                    
                    if(j==8)
                    cout<<"|";  
                    
                }
                
            cout<<"\n";
            if(i==8)
            cout<<"\t\t-------------------------\n";    
            
        
        }
        
        
}


int validate(int sudoku) // function to validate the input SU-DO-CU
{
    unsigned i,j,k,n,count=0;
//..........................row validation
    for(i=0; i<9; i++)
        for(j=0; j<9; j++)
            for(k=0;k<9;k++)
                {
                    if(sudoku==1 && k!=j && su_in[i][j]!=0)
                       {
                        if(su_in[i][j]==su_in[i][k])
                        return 1;
                       }
                     else if(sudoku==2 && k!=j )
                       {
                        if(su_out[i][j]==su_out[i][k])
                        return 1;
                       }  
            
                    
                }
//..................................colume validation
    for(i=0;  i<9;  i++)
        for(j=0;  j<9;  j++)
            for(k=0;  k<9;  k++)
                {
                    if(sudoku==1 && k!=j && su_in[j][i]!=0)
                       {
                        if(su_in[j][i]==su_in[k][i])
                        return 1;
                       }
                     else if(sudoku==2 && k!=i )
                       {
                        if(su_out[j][i]==su_out[j][k])
                        
                        return 1;
                       }    
                }
    // each box validating.......................
    for(i=0;  i<=6;  i=i+3)
        for(j=0; j<=6; j=j+3)
        {
            if(box_validate(i,j,sudoku)==1)
            return 1;
        }
    
    // sum validation for output....
    
    if(sudoku==2)
    {
        for(i=0; i<9; i++)
        for(j=0; j<9; j++)
            count=count+su_out[i][j];
        
    if(count!=405) return 1;
    }
    
    
        return 0;           
                
}


int box_validate(int i,int j,int sudoku)
{   
    unsigned k=j,n=i;
    int temp_i=i,temp_j=j,temp_k=k, temp_n=n;
        for(i=temp_i;  i<temp_i+3;  i++)
        for(j=temp_j;  j<temp_j+3;  j++)
            for(k=temp_k;  k<temp_k+3;  k++)
                {           
                  if(sudoku==1 && k!=j && su_in[i][j]!=0)
                 {
                    if(su_in[i][j]==su_in[i][k])
                     return 1;
                    
                        for(n=temp_n;  n<temp_n+3;  n++)
                        {
                             if(sudoku==1 &&  su_in[i][j]!=0)
                              if(k==j && n==i)
                                ;else 
                                  if(su_in[i][j]==su_in[n][k])
                                    return 1;
                                
                        }
                }
        

                if(sudoku==2 && k!=j )
                {
                    if(su_out[i][j]==su_out[i][k])
                     return 1;
                    
                        for(n=temp_n;  n<temp_n+3;  n++)
                        {
                             if(sudoku==1 )
                              if(k==j && n==i)
                                ;else 
                                  if(su_out[i][j]==su_out[n][k])
                                    return 1;
                                
                        

                          }
                }
            }
    return 0;
    
}


int solve()
{
    unsigned i,j,k,m,n,x;   

struct chance cell[9][9];

    for(i=0; i<9; i++)
        for(j=0; j<9; j++)
            if(su_in[i][j]==0)
                for(k=0;k<9; k++)
                cell[i][j].poss[k]=k+1;
                
                /*
    for(i=0; i<9; i++)
        for(j=0; j<9; j++)
            if(su_in[i][j]==0)
                for(k=0;k<9; k++)
                {   su_out[i][j]=cell[i][j].poss[k]=k+1;            
                        su_out[i][j]=cell[i][j].poss[k];
                        for(m=0; m<9; m++)
                          for(n=0; n<9; n++)
                          for(x=1; x<=9; x++)
                          { if(x!=k+1)
                            cell[m][n].poss[x]==x;
                            if(validate(2)==0)
                               return 0;
                       }
            }*/
            
        for(i=0; i<9; i++)
        for(j=0; j<9; j++)
            if(su_in[i][j]==0)
            while (validate(2)==0)
            {
            
                for(k=0;k<9; k++)
                {   su_out[i][j]=k+1;           
                        for(m=i+1; m <9 ; m++)
                          for(n=0; n <9 ; n++)
                            for(x=1; x<=9; x++)
                          { su_out[m][n]=x;
                            if(validate(2)==0)
                               return 0;
                       }
            }
          }
}
```

Comment: " I have seen some codes online about the sudoku solving but I feel hard to analyze them. " <- Don't try to find code, but try to find algorithms, i.e. high-level descriptions or pseudocode. In order to understand what's going on, that will help a lot more than other people's code.

Comment: When wikipedia has an article called "Sudoku solving algorithms" and it's the first result on a google search, you just know somebody hasn't done their homework. Also, strip out old comments in code samples, unless they're explanatory.

Comment: Once I made [a solver in C](https://github.com/jakub-m/sudoku-solver) following the excellent ["Algorithm design manual"](http://www.amazon.com/Algorithm-Design-Manual-Steven-Skiena/dp/1848000693). So you can check both the algorithm description (in the book) and the code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
#define UNASSIGNED 0
#define N 9

bool FindUnassignedLocation(int grid[N][N], int &row, int &col);
bool isSafe(int grid[N][N], int row, int col, int num);

/* assign values to all unassigned locations for Sudoku solution  
 */
bool SolveSudoku(int grid[N][N])
{
    int row, col;
    if (!FindUnassignedLocation(grid, row, col))
       return true;
    for (int num = 1; num <= 9; num++)
    {
    if (isSafe(grid, row, col, num))
    {
        grid[row][col] = num;
        if (SolveSudoku(grid))
            return true;
        grid[row][col] = UNASSIGNED;
    }
    }
    return false;
}

/* Searches the grid to find an entry that is still unassigned. */
bool FindUnassignedLocation(int grid[N][N], int &row, int &col)
{
    for (row = 0; row < N; row++)
        for (col = 0; col < N; col++)
            if (grid[row][col] == UNASSIGNED)
                return true;
    return false;
}

/* Returns whether any assigned entry n the specified row matches 
   the given number. */
bool UsedInRow(int grid[N][N], int row, int num)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < N; col++)
    if (grid[row][col] == num)
        return true;
    return false;
}

/* Returns whether any assigned entry in the specified column matches 
   the given number. */
bool UsedInCol(int grid[N][N], int col, int num)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < N; row++)
        if (grid[row][col] == num)
            return true;
    return false;
}

/* Returns whether any assigned entry within the specified 3x3 box matches 
   the given number. */
bool UsedInBox(int grid[N][N], int boxStartRow, int boxStartCol, int num)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
        for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
            if (grid[row+boxStartRow][col+boxStartCol] == num)
                return true;
    return false;
}

/* Returns whether it will be legal to assign num to the given row,col location. 
 */
bool isSafe(int grid[N][N], int row, int col, int num)
{
    return !UsedInRow(grid, row, num) && !UsedInCol(grid, col, num) &&
       !UsedInBox(grid, row - row % 3 , col - col % 3, num);
}

void printGrid(int grid[N][N])
{
    for (int row = 0; row < N; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < N; col++)
            cout<<grid[row][col]<<"  ";
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int grid[N][N] = {{3, 0, 6, 5, 0, 8, 4, 0, 0},
                      {5, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                      {0, 8, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1},
                      {0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 8, 0},
                      {9, 0, 0, 8, 6, 3, 0, 0, 5},
                      {0, 5, 0, 0, 9, 0, 6, 0, 0},
                      {1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 0},
                      {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 4},
                      {0, 0, 5, 2, 0, 6, 3, 0, 0}};
    if (SolveSudoku(grid) == true)
        printGrid(grid);
    else
        cout<<"No solution exists"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In a quick check, I found one glitch ...  2 values of 3 in row 0 were not detected (i.e. invalid user input), and the error was continued to the final output.

Comment: You don't initialize row and col when you do the below the first time. Guessing it's a bad practice?

int row, col;
    if (!FindUnassignedLocation(grid, row, col))

Answer (score 6):

Here's my code:
I think it's the best.

```
/*
 *  File: Sudoku-Solver.cc
 *
 *  Created On: 12, April 2016
 *      Author: Shlomo Gottlieb
 *
 * Description: This program holds A sudoku board (size: 9*9),
 *              it allows the user to input values that he choices
 *              and finds the first rational solution.
 *              The program also prints the sudoku whether A solution
 *              was found or not.
 *
 */

//========= Includes =========//
#include <iostream>

//========= Using ==========//
using namespace std;

//========= Constants =========//
const int N = 3;            // The size of 1 square in the sudoku.
const int EMPTY = 0;        // A sign for an empty cell.
const int STOP_INPUT = -1;  // A sign for stop get input.

//====== Function Declaration ======//
void input_sud(int sud[][N*N]);
bool fill_sud(int sud[][N*N], int row, int col);
void print_sud(const int sud[][N*N]);
bool is_legal(const int sud[][N*N], int row, int col, int val);
bool is_row_ok(const int row[], int col, int val);
bool is_col_ok(const int sud[][N*N], int row, int col, int val);
bool is_sqr_ok(const int sud[][N*N], int row, int col, int val);

//========== Main ===========//
int main()
{
    int sud[N*N][N*N] = { { EMPTY } };  // The sudoku board.

    input_sud(sud);
    fill_sud(sud, 0, 0);
    print_sud(sud);

    return 0;
}

//======== Input Sudoku ========//
// Gets the input for the sudoku,
// 0 means an empty cell.
void input_sud(int sud[][N*N])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < N*N; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < N*N; j++)
            cin >> sud[i][j];
}

//======== Fill Sudoku =========//
// Tries to fill-in the given sudoku board
// according to the sudoku rules.
// Returns whether it was possible to solve it or not.
bool fill_sud(int sud[][N*N], int row, int col)
{
    // Points to the row number of the next cell.
    int next_row = (col == N*N - 1) ? row + 1 : row;

    // Points to the column number of the next cell.
    int next_col = (col + 1) % (N*N);

    // If we get here, it means we succeed to solve the sudoku.
    if(row == N*N)  
        return true;

    // Checks if we are allowed to change the value of the current cell.
    // If we're not, then we're moving to the next one.
    if(sud[row][col] != EMPTY)
        return fill_sud(sud, next_row, next_col);

    // We're about to try and find the legal and appropriate value
    // to put in the current cell.
    for(int value = 1; value <= N*N; value++)
    {
        sud[row][col] = value;

        // Checks if 'value' can stay in the current cell,
        // and returns true if it does.
        if(is_legal(sud, row, col, value) && fill_sud(sud, next_row, next_col))
            return true;

        // Trial failed!
        sud[row][col] = EMPTY;
    }

    // None of the values solved the sudoku.
    return false;
}

//======== Print Sudoku ========//
// Prints the sudoku Graphically.
void print_sud(const int sud[][N*N])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < N*N; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < N*N; j++)
            cout << sud[i][j] << ' ';
        cout << endl;
    }
}

//========== Is Legal ==========//
// Checks and returns whether it's legal
// to put 'val' in A specific cell.
bool is_legal(const int sud[][N*N], int row, int col, int val)
{
    return (is_row_ok(sud[row], col, val) &&
            is_col_ok(sud, row, col, val) &&
            is_sqr_ok(sud, row, col, val));
}

//========= Is Row OK =========//
// Checks and returns whether it's legal
// to put 'val' in A specific row.
bool is_row_ok(const int row[], int col, int val)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < N*N; i++)
        if(i != col && row[i] == val)
            return false;       // Found the same value again!

    return true;
}

//========= Is Column OK =========//
// Checks and returns whether it's legal
// to put 'val' in A specific column.
bool is_col_ok(const int sud[][N*N], int row, int col, int val)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < N*N; i++)
        if(i != row && sud[i][col] == val)
            return false;       // Found the same value again!

    return true;
}

//========= Is Square OK =========//
// Checks and returns whether it's legal
// to put 'val' in A specific square.
bool is_sqr_ok(const int sud[][N*N], int row, int col, int val)
{
    int row_corner = (row / N) * N;
    // Holds the row number of the current square corner cell.

    int col_corner = (col / N) * N;
    // Holds the column number of the current square corner cell.

    for(int i = row_corner; i < (row_corner + N); i++)
        for(int j = col_corner; j < (col_corner + N); j++)
            if((i != row || j != col) && sud[i][j] == val)
                return false;       // Found the same value again!

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I am a recursion fan, and very much like your code. Excellent brevity, quite readable.  I did find one small glitch however ... the "is_xxx_ok()" functions do not detect an invalid user input.  unit test: provide 2 or more '3's in any single row (or col, or blk).

Comment: Thank you @DOUGLASO.MOEN, you're right about the glitch, it was just homework so we had to assume the input is valid.

Answer (score 1):

```
//here's a pseudo sudoku solver:

#include <iostream> 
#include <cmath>
#include "time.h"
//for(int i=0; i< ++i){}
using namespace std;

int main(){
 int a[9][9]={{0,7,0,0,2,0,1,0,0},
             {6,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0},
             {2,0,0,3,0,0,5,0,0},
             {0,0,0,0,3,0,0,6,0},
             {0,6,4,7,0,0,0,8,0},
             {0,5,0,0,9,0,0,4,0},
      /*54*/ {0,4,0,0,7,0,9,0,0},
             {0,2,0,0,0,8,0,5,0},
             {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}};/*this is the grid. I need to use two so that I can use one as a constant reference*/
             
  int a2[9][9]={{0,7,0,0,2,0,1,0,0},
             {6,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0},
             {2,0,0,3,0,0,5,0,0},
             {0,0,0,0,3,0,0,6,0},
             {0,6,4,7,0,0,0,8,0},
             {0,5,0,0,9,0,0,4,0},
             {0,4,0,0,7,0,9,0,0},
             {0,2,0,0,0,8,0,5,0},
             {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}}; 
                            
int x=0,y=0,z=0;
int oo=0,o=0,ooo=0,oooo=0; 
 for(int i=0; i<9; ++i)/*this is the double for loop.  to keep track of  the cells*/
 {
 for(int j=0; j<9; ++j)
 { 
 if(!a2[i][j])
 {a://label that if something doesn't work, to restart here.
 ++a[i][j];//increment the number in the cell by 1.
  if(a[i][j]>9)/*if no valid number is found/the number is out of range, execute the if statement.  **This is the backtracking algorithm.***/
{      
             a[i][j]=0;//erase the invalid number.
             --j;if(j<0){--i;j=8;} /*if j equals < 0, j is reset to 8, as the first 9 numbers are easy to find, and if j needs to be reset, there will always be a number in the j equals 8 cell.  The "i" will never be less than zero, if it is a valid puzzle, so the j=8 will only happen after i is > 0.*/ 
    while(a2[i][j]){--j;if(j<0){--i;j=8;}}/*if there was a number present from the beginning, skip it until a variable cell space is found.*/         

  goto a;//jump to a: and increment the current number in the cell by 1.
  } 
 if(j<3){o=0;oo=3;}if(j>2 && j<6){o=3;oo=6;}/*locate the 3X9 grid j is in.*/
 if(j>5){o=6;oo=9;}

 if(i<3){ooo=0;oooo=3;}if(i>2 && i<6){ooo=3;oooo=6;}/*locate the 9X3 grid i is in.*/
 if(i>5){ooo=6;oooo=9;}       
                               
 for(int u=ooo; u<oooo; ++u)/*intersect the 3X9 and 9X3 grids to create a searchable 3X3 grid.*/   
 { 
 for(int p=o; p<oo; ++p)
 {
     
     if(a[u][p]==a[i][j]){++x;if(x>1){x=0;goto a;}}/*if the number is not valid, go to a: and increment the number in the cell by 1.*/
            
  }
  
  }    
 x=0;
  for(int n=0; n<9; ++n)
  {
  if(a[i][j]==a[i][n]){++y; if(y>1){y=0;goto a;}}/*if no valid number is found, goto a: and increment the number in the cell by 1.*/
  }y=0;
  
  for(int m=0; m<9; ++m)
  {
   if(a[i][j]==a[m][j]){++y; if(y>1){y=0;goto a;}}//""     
  } y=0;   

  
  } 
  
  }
  } 

for(int i=0; i<9; ++i)//print the completed puzzle.
{
  for(int j=0; j<9; ++j)
    {
     cout<<a[i][j]<<" ";
    }  
    cout<<endl;//print on the next line after 9 digits are printed.  
}

return 0;
}

//if no valid puzzle is found, the screen hangs.  -  Harjinder




/*random sudokus' can be generated and solved in one program by copying the following code into an editor. hit enter to generate and solve a new puzzle:

//the following works the same way as above except that it is 2 solvers in a continuous while loop

//the first solver, to generate the random puzzle:

#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

int main(){
 while(1){     
 int a[9][9]={0}, a2[9][9]={0};


 int w=0, x=0,y=0,z=0, yy=0, oo=0,o=0,ooo=0,oooo=0;
 for(int i=0; i<9; ++i)
 {
 for(int j=0; j<9; ++j)
 { 
   if(!a2[i][j])
   {srand(time(0));if(w<5){++w;a[i][j]=rand()%9;}a:++a[i][j];//generate a random number from 0 to 9 and and then increment by 1. 
       
   if(a[i][j]>9)
  { 
             a[i][j]=0; 
             --j;if(j<0){--i;j=8;}
   while(a2[i][j]){--j;if(j<0){--i;j=8;}}


  goto a;
  } 
 if(j<3){o=0;oo=3;}if(j>2 && j<6){o=3;oo=6;}
 if(j>5){o=6;oo=9;}

 if(i<3){ooo=0;oooo=3;}if(i>2 && i<6){ooo=3;oooo=6;}
 if(i>5){ooo=6;oooo=9;}

 for(int u=ooo; u<oooo; ++u)
 {
 for(int p=o; p<oo; ++p)
 {
  if(a[u][p]==a[i][j]){++x;if(x>1){x=0;goto a;}}
  }}
x=0;
 for(int n=0; n<9; ++n)
 {
 if(a[i][j]==a[i][n]){++y; if(y>1){y=0;goto a;}}
 }y=0;

 for(int m=0; m<9; ++m)
 {
 if(a[i][j]==a[m][j]){++y; if(y>1){y=0;goto a;}}
 } y=0;}//if 
 }
  }
  
//the second part below is to add zeros' to the puzzle, and copy the puzzle into the second solver arrays. 
int n=40;//adjusts the amount of empty spaces. works only if landed on non-zero, or else the zero will be counted.
x=0;int xx=0;
o=0;int pp=0,ppp=0;
while(o<n)
{
 
pp=rand()%9;
ppp=rand()%9; 
 a[pp][ppp]=0;  
  pp=rand()%9;
 ppp=rand()%9;    
a[ppp][pp]=0;    

 ++o;
}
for(int i=0; i<9; ++i)
{
for(int j=0; j<9; ++j)
    {
     cout<<a[i][j]<<" ";
     
    }
     cout<<endl;
}
x=0,xx=0;

cout<<endl<<endl;
int a5[9][9]={0}, a6[9][9]={0};x=-1;
for(int i=0; i<9; ++i)
{
for(int j=0; j<9; ++j)
    {
     ++x;
     a5[i][j]=a[i][j];//copy first puzzle with added zeros into the new array.
     
    }
     
}
for(int i=0; i<9; ++i)
{
for(int j=0; j<9; ++j)
    {
     a6[i][j]=a5[i][j];//copy the updated puzzle with zeros, into the constant reference array.
     
    }
     
}

x=0;
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//second solver to solve the zero updated array:
cout<<endl<<endl;
o=0;
y=0,z=0;
oo=0,ooo=0,oooo=0;
for(int i=0; i<9; ++i)
{
for(int j=0; j<9; ++j)
{
if(!a6[i][j])
{c5:
 ++a5[i][j];
  if(a5[i][j]>9)
 {
             a5[i][j]=0;
             --j;if(j<0){--i;j=8;}
    while(a6[i][j]){--j;if(j<0){--i;j=8;}}
     
  goto c5;
  }
 if(j<3){o=0;oo=3;}if(j>2 && j<6){o=3;oo=6;}
 if(j>5){o=6;oo=9;}

 if(i<3){ooo=0;oooo=3;}if(i>2 && i<6){ooo=3;oooo=6;}
 if(i>5){ooo=6;oooo=9;}

 for(int u=ooo; u<oooo; ++u)
 {
 for(int p=o; p<oo; ++p)
 {
  if(a5[u][p]==a5[i][j]){++x;if(x>1){x=0;goto c5;}}
 }}
x=0;
for(int n=0; n<9; ++n)
{
if(a5[i][j]==a5[i][n]){++y; if(y>1){y=0;goto c5;}}
 }y=0;

for(int m=0; m<9; ++m)
{
 if(a5[i][j]==a5[m][j]){++y; if(y>1){y=0;goto c5;}}
 } y=0;} }
 }

for(int i=0; i<9; ++i)
{
for(int j=0; j<9; ++j)
    {
     cout<<a5[i][j]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

cout<<endl;
system("pause");//hit enter to load a new puzzle
}
 
return 0;
} */
```

Comment: This is the simplest way I could think of to do this.  No activation records required.

Comment: Could you please 1) properly indent your code, 2) use meaningful variable names (rather than `o`, `oo`, `ooo` etc) and 3) add some explanations to help the reader understand what your code is doing and how it's actually solving Sudokus?

Comment: Here's what's happening: first, if no number is in the cell=0, the cell is incremented by one. Then the number in the cell is checked for duplicates in it's respective 3X3 grid. then it is checked longitudinally, and horizontally. If it works, the number is added into the cell and i or j is incremented for the next cell.  If the number does not fit, it is deleted and i or j is decremented to the previous cell and incremented by 1..... If no solution exists, the screen hangs.

Comment: I had to totally understand what I was trying to do before I wrote the program.  This method is how I was able to solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. Could you edit that into your answer? (and as for a general rule on StackOverflow: a code-only answer has very little value compared to code + explanations)

Answer (score 0):

The answer given above is similar to what a lot of people have posted at several websites like https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sudoku-backtracking-7/. TBH, those solutions are not intuitive to me when they don't initialize row and col and call it in the FindUnassignedLocation function. I wanted to give it a shot myself with slight help from another answer I found on LeetCode. If it helps anyone, here you go.

```
// https://www.pramp.com/challenge/O5PGrqGEyKtq9wpgw6XP

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// Print the sudoku
void print(vector<vector<char>> board){
    for(int i = 0; i < board.size(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < board[i].size(); j++){
            cout << board[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

// Check if sudoku is all filled up
bool checkIfFilled(vector<vector<char>> board){
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
            if(board[i][j] == '.')
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

// Check if a given number can be inserted at a given position
bool checkIfInsertOkay(vector<vector<char>> board, int x, int y, char num){
    // Check row if num already exists
    for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
        if(board[x][j] == num)
            return false;
    }
    // Check column if num already exists
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        if(board[i][y] == num)
            return false;
    }
    // Check 3x3 gird if num already exists
    // Find the corners
    // Find i
    if(x < 3)
        x = 0;
    else if(x < 6)
        x = 3;
    else
        x = 6;
    // Find j
    if(y < 3)
        y = 0;
    else if(y < 6)
        y = 3;
    else
        y = 6;
    // Check the 3x3 box
    for(int i = x; i < x+3; i++){
        for(int j = y; j < y+3; j++){
            if(board[i][j] == num)
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

// Helper function because of const issues
bool sudokuSolveHelper(vector<vector<char>> &board){
    // Base condition - if sudoku gets completely filled
    if(checkIfFilled(board))
        return true;

    // Iterate through the sudoku
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
            // If empty space
            if(board[i][j] == '.'){
                for(int k = 1; k <= 9; k++){
                    // Check if char(k) can be inserted at this empty location
                    char ch = '0' + k;
                    if(checkIfInsertOkay(board, i, j, ch)){
                        // Put k in this empty location and check
                        board[i][j] = ch;
                        // Check if done
                        bool flag = sudokuSolveHelper(board);
                        if(flag)
                            return true;
                        else
                            // Else, backtrack by making it empty again
                            board[i][j] = '.';
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

// Return true if a correct sudoku can be formed
// Apply backtracking
// Time complexity = O(9^empty spaces)
bool sudokuSolve(vector<vector<char>> &board){
    return sudokuSolveHelper(board);
}

int main() {

    vector<vector<char>> board = {
        {'.','.','.','7','.','.','3','.','1'},
        {'3','.','.','9','.','.','.','.','.'},
        {'.','4','.','3','1','.','2','.','.'},
        {'.','6','.','4','.','.','5','.','.'},
        {'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'},
        {'.','.','1','.','.','8','.','4','.'},
        {'.','.','6','.','2','1','.','5','.'},
        {'.','.','.','.','.','9','.','.','8'},
        {'8','.','5','.','.','4','.','.','.'}
    };
    print(board);
    bool flag = sudokuSolve(board);
    if(flag){
        cout << "A solution exists as below\n";
        print(board);
    }
    else
        cout << "No solution exists!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//the following works like the one above accept there is a while loop instead of goto statements:

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "time.h"
//for(int i=0; i< ++i){}
using namespace std;

int main(){
int a[9][9]={{2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
             {0,0,0,9,0,6,0,0,0},
             {0,0,0,8,0,1,7,2,0},
             {9,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0},
             {0,0,8,0,0,0,2,0,4},
             {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3},
      /*54*/ {1,0,3,0,0,5,0,0,9},
             {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
             {0,4,6,2,0,0,0,0,0}};

 int a2[9][9]={{2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
             {0,0,0,9,0,6,0,0,0},
             {0,0,0,8,0,1,7,2,0},
             {9,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0},
             {0,0,8,0,0,0,2,0,4},
             {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3},
             {1,0,3,0,0,5,0,0,9},
             {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
             {0,4,6,2,0,0,0,0,0}};

 int x=0,y=0,z=0;
 int colPlusThree=0,col=0,row=0,rowPlusThree=0;
  for(int i=0; i<9; ++i)
  {
  for(int j=0; j<9; ++j)
  {z=0;
  if(!a2[i][j])
  {while(z==0){ //the master while loop. loops until a valid number is found.
  ++a[i][j];
  if(a[i][j]>9)
 {
             a[i][j]=0;
             --j;if(j<0){--i;j=8;}
    while(a2[i][j]){--j;if(j<0){--i;j=8;}}

 ++a[i][j];if(a[i][j]>9){--j;}
 }      

if(j<3){col=0;colPlusThree=3;}if(j>2 && j<6){col=3;colPlusThree=6;}
if(j>5){col=6;colPlusThree=9;}

if(i<3){row=0;rowPlusThree=3;}if(i>2 && i<6){row=3;rowPlusThree=6;}
if(i>5){row=6;rowPlusThree=9;}

 for(int u=row; u<rowPlusThree; ++u)
 {
 for(int p=col; p<colPlusThree; ++p)
 {
  if(a[u][p]==a[i][j]){++x;if(x>1){u=rowPlusThree;break;}}
 }}if(x<2){z=1;}else{z=0;}x=0;

for(int n=0; n<9; ++n)
{
if(z==0){y=2;break;}
if(a[i][j]==a[i][n]){++y; if(y>1){break;}}
}if(y<2){z=1;}else{z=0;}y=0;

for(int m=0; m<9; ++m)
{
 if(z==0){y=2;break;}     
 if(a[i][j]==a[m][j]){++y; if(y>1){break;}}
} if(y<2){z=1;}else{z=0;}y=0;}}}}

for(int i=0; i<9; ++i)
{
for(int j=0; j<9; ++j)
    {
     cout<<a[i][j]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

return 0;
}//  -  Harjinder
```